# increase ssh timeout

Tags: linux, ssh, timeout

I'm trying to connect to a mobile host connected over a 3G cell router from linux with

```
ssh root@74.198.25.XXX -p 2200
```

and all I immediately get is (doesn't even seem to run into a timeout)

```
ssh: connect to host 74.198.25.220 port 2200: Network is unreachable
```

However, when I try the same IP on port 2200 with putty on Windows, it presents my with the password prompt just fine as I'd expect.
What's going on here, do I need to increment my ssh timeout period to get this going or what?

Thank you,
Ron

Comment: It seems like your device's IP is blocked. Maybe a firewall block on that ipaddress, fail2ban? And does the 3G allows use of that port? Some providers only allow the standard internet ports...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Network unreachable implies the following:

1. The host is not on your local network
2. The network the host is on is not reachable from your local network

The reason for this could be many, but things to check would be:

- Ensure that the device you're connecting from has a proper network connection
- Ensure that the device you're connecting from has a proper gateway setup
- Ensure that the device you're connecting from has a route leading to the target (Normally sorted by the abvoe)
- Ensure that there's nothing between you and the target device firewalling port 2200

Comment: ZONK! Yep Jarmund! My fault! Thanks for nudging me!